Production slot not using Production as ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable
I have an issue where my web app in the production slot does not connect to my DB if I have Production specified as a variable. My Staging, UAT, and Development slot work perfectly with their variables set as their names.
However, when I had Development, Staging, or UAT as the variable for my Production slot, it worked. Additionally, when I set the Production variable to blank (''), it worked? Please could someone assist?
I have 4 .json files for appsetings.[slot_name].json.

Can you check if you have pre-defined the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT varaible value in your web.config file when deploying to Production slot? If yes, you can remove the variable in web.config and check if it can apply the correct value.

On the other hand, can you share more details about how you define the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable in Production Slot and other slots.

I define the variable in the web app service. Under configuration I set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT var to Production, and it did not work. When I set it to blank '', it works?

Can you check if the Production Slot have a web.config file? You can check if the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT has been defined in the web.config file. In this case, if you set the variable to blank in web app configuration, it will use the default value in web.config.

I don't believe I have a web.config file? I created a C# web app. Everything works perfectly though?

@WorkingProgrammer - Not locally, check for the web.config in the deployed App Service in KUDU => Site/wwwroot folder.The config file will be created by default

I don't have a web.config folder. Just hostingstart.html, and output.tag.gz. Everything works perfectly though? My Staging slot uses the Staging Env, UAT, the UAT Env, Development the Development Env, and Production uses '', which defaults to the Producton Env.

If possible please share your code repo.Do you have any environment variable set in the azure app service.

FYI comments are not for extended discussion. @WorkingProgrammer - please edit your question with additional details such as your configuration, code, etc. (a [mcve]).

Issue has not been sorted, but I shall close it as the current solution works without issues. I have kept the Environment Variable set to ''.
